# SQLQuery for non Opens for 2 Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to build SQL query for non-openers for 2 Journeys: X and Y
Could you please advice what is wrong here? I didn't get any error. Simply I got 0 results or results are wrong.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
s.SubscriberKey as SubscriberKey,
jr.JourneyName as JourneyName
From [_Sent] as s
inner join [_Job] as j on s.JobID = j.JobID
inner join [_Open] as o on o.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
inner join [_JourneyActivity] as ja on s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID
inner join [_Journey] as jr on ja.VersionID = jr.VersionID
where jr.JourneyName = 'X' or jr.JourneyName = 'Y'
and o.SubscriberKey = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues:

1. Open View JOIN
   a) should be LEFT JOIN to Sent view
   b) join should include more fields--batchid, listid, jobib & SubscriberKey--See documentation.
   c) also confirm join field to journey views.

I believe fixing 1A item is your problem that is SQL 101 issue that is causing this

Comment: I've updated SQL but I'm still not receiving any records.